# AngularJS model won't update immediately if it is changed in a jQuery delegated event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have set up a jsfiddle for my problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/limdauto/bNbKk/2/). Basically I'm trying to let user generate HTML radio group by dynamically constructing a table of options associated with this group. I then store all of these options in an Angular model called `$scope.options`, which is an array. Every single time a new row is added to the options table, a new option object is pushed into the options array. Pretty simple, really.

The problem is my `$scope.options` model is not updated immediately after the event handler terminates. Instead, it's only updated when another event is triggered. To demonstrate, please head over to my fiddle and add 2 options to the table. You will see that the number of options doesn't change after you add option 1 but changes when you begin adding option 2.

```
// add option to the table
$("#table-radio-options").on("click", "button.btn-confirm-option", function (event) {
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var $optionText = $tr.find(".option-text").first();
    var $optionValue = $tr.find(".option-value").first();
    // add to the list of options in this scope
    $scope.options.push({
        text: $optionText.val(),
        value: $optionValue.val()
    });
    // change the form into table row with data value
    $optionText.replaceWith("<span>{0}</span>".format($optionText.val()));
    $optionValue.replaceWith("<span>{0}</span>".format($optionValue.val()));
    // remove the confirm 
    $(this).remove();
});
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the $scope changes within the [$apply()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply), if you are dealing with a non angular method

```
// add option to the table
$("#table-radio-options").on("click", "button.btn-confirm-option", function (event) {
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var $optionText = $tr.find(".option-text").first();
    var $optionValue = $tr.find(".option-value").first();

    //add this
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        // add to the list of options in this scope
        $scope.options.push({
            text: $optionText.val(),
            value: $optionValue.val()
        });
    })

    // change the form into table row with data value
    $optionText.replaceWith("<span>{0}</span>".format($optionText.val()));
    $optionValue.replaceWith("<span>{0}</span>".format($optionValue.val()));
    // remove the confirm 
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: omg thanks so much. It works. But could you please explain why it doesn't update immediately but I have to invoke apply manually?

Comment: AngularJS uses dirty checking which loops through all your model attributes and finds something to change. This is called the `$digest` cycle. The digest cycle doesn't know to start when you change something in jQuery, therefore you need to use $scope.$apply() to let angular know that the model has changed. This can be observed by not using $scope.$apply(), make the changes, then simply type into any ng-model input, you will notice that all the queued changes will THEN apply as soon as you make angularjs act upon one of its models.

Comment: @LimH. the changes made to the scope is updated in the UI when the attached watches are executed... when a method is executed from angular js it is handled internally... but when an non angular method invokation like dom event handler is executed angular js does not know that the objects are changed